# How to place widgets with Gtk::Grid similarly to Gtk::Table in Gtkmm-3

Tags: c++, gtkmm3

Originally I learned pyGtk. After a few months I decided to switch to Gtkmm. Reading the oficial documentation it tells that Gtk::Table is deprecated and I should use Gtk::Grid instead.

If I want to place the widget between the 2nd and 3rd row, and between the 4th and 5th column, I use this code with Gtk::Table.

```
// Create variable.        
Gtk::Table table;

//Initiate table.
table(10,10,true);

//Place the widget in the proper position.
// table.attach(widget, left_attach, right_attach, top_attach, bottom_attach);
table.attach(widget,4,5,2,3);
```

After reading about Gtk::Grid I tried the same thing, but using Gtk::Grid this time.

```
// Create variable.        
Gtk::Grid grid;

//Place the widget in the proper position.
//grid.attach(widget, left, top, higth, width); 
grid.attach(widget,4,2,1,1);
```

But when I try the last code the widget(a button), remains placed in the top left corner. Anyone have a clue about what I'm doing wrong? Does Gtk::Grid has the capacity to do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

The button remains in the top left corner because there are no other widgets in the first row or first three columns to take up any space, so they collapse to zero.

Probably what you want is

```
grid.set_row_homogeneous(true);
grid.set_column_homogeneous(true);
```

followed by attaching blank widgets at position 0, 0 and position 9, 9 to make sure the grid has 10 rows and 10 columns.